# CPU cache information for Raspberry Pi not shown

Tags: linux, unix, debian

I want to know the size of L1 and L2 cache as well as other metrics of my Raspberry Pi 3B I'm using.

However, for whatever reason I cannot get any information regarding the cache. Commands such as `getconf -a | grep CACHE` give me:

```
LEVEL1_ICACHE_SIZE                 0
LEVEL1_ICACHE_ASSOC                0
LEVEL1_ICACHE_LINESIZE             0
LEVEL1_DCACHE_SIZE                 0
LEVEL1_DCACHE_ASSOC                0
LEVEL1_DCACHE_LINESIZE             0
LEVEL2_CACHE_SIZE                  0
LEVEL2_CACHE_ASSOC                 0
LEVEL2_CACHE_LINESIZE              0
LEVEL3_CACHE_SIZE                  0
LEVEL3_CACHE_ASSOC                 0
LEVEL3_CACHE_LINESIZE              0
LEVEL4_CACHE_SIZE                  0
LEVEL4_CACHE_ASSOC                 0
LEVEL4_CACHE_LINESIZE              0
```

Other tools like `lshw` give no cache information also.

What is the cause of this and how can I get this cache info?

Answer (score 0):

It says on the [Raspberry Pi Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi#Processor):

> The Raspberry Pi 4 uses a Broadcom BCM2711 SoC with a 1.5 GHz 64-bit
> quad-core ARM Cortex-A72 processor, with 1 MB shared L2 cache.

And yes, I would would also like to have the commands working like on the most other chips/OSs (I don't know exactly who is responsible for that).